# MySQL query filter properly , some where conditions are ignored

Tags: mysql

I got the following sql :

```
SELECT * FROM LISTING WHERE 

paused = 0   and city = 3 or city = 1 or city = 2 
and rent = 1 and bedrooms = 1 and type = 1
```

my result is that: it meets the condition that `city = 3 or city=1 or city=2`

but it ignores the rest : `and rent = 1 and bedrooms = 1 and type = 1`

I'd like the result to have multiple cities but the requirements: `and rent = 1 and bedrooms = 1 and type = 1` to be met, right now it just outputs results for multiple cities with no further filter by **rent**, **bedrooms**, **type** .

please help, Thank You.

Comment: you're mixing `and` and `or` without `()` to enforce your desired parsing/execution order. you need to read up about [operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html)

Comment: It's interesting. The answer you selected is exactly the same as mine. But, it has been posted later than mine. May I know why you selected that instead of my answer?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know you posted first, I'll fix it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to divide the OR part

```
SELECT * FROM LISTING WHERE 

paused = 0   and (city = 3 or city = 1 or city = 2 )
and rent = 1 and bedrooms = 1 and type = 1
```

The better way is:

```
SELECT * FROM LISTING WHERE 

paused = 0 and city IN (1,2,3)
and rent = 1 and bedrooms = 1 and type = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using multiple `OR` conditions, it would be better to use the `IN` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM LISTING 
WHERE paused = 0
AND city IN (1, 2, 3)
AND rent = 1 
AND bedrooms = 1 
AND type = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
SELECT * FROM LISTING WHERE 

paused = 0   and ( city = 3 or city = 1 or city = 2 )
and rent = 1 and bedrooms = 1 and type = 1;
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM LISTING WHERE 

paused = 0   and city IN (1,2,3)
and rent = 1 and bedrooms = 1 and type = 1;
```